# Node-mysql Pool disconnecting after a few hours

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

After a few hours of running my express node application the server loses connection to the mysql server. I am using a connection pool so it shouldn't be disconnecting. Here is how I initialize the pool:

```
pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit    : 10,
  host               : creds.mysql_host,
  port               : creds.mysql_port,
  database           : creds.mysql_db,
  user               : creds.mysql_user,
  password           : creds.mysql_pass,
  multipleStatements : true
});
```

To talk to the mysql server I do:

```
pool.query("statement", [inputs], callback);
```

Could the server be crashing and the pool cannot reconnect? Do I need to do `connection.release()` even when using `connection.query`? The error the server reports is:

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. 
at Protocol.end (/opt/node-v0.10.20-linux-x64/IM/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:73:13)
at Socket.onend (stream.js:79:10)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:920:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```